# Inconsistent counting columns of insert in DAO

Tags: java

I'm developing a n-tier java app and when implement the insert method, I get this error:
(conn=146) Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I´m using a mariadb database and a logic-DAO-View model

Here is the code:

DAO:

```
         try {
            Statement st = conex.getConnection().createStatement();
            st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO abas001 (abas_cod, abas_cnt, abas_vol, abas_und) VALUES ('"
                  + miAbasto.getAbas_cod() + "', '"
                  + miAbasto.getAbas_cnt() + "', '"
                  + miAbasto.getAbas_vol() + "', '"
                  + miAbasto.getAbas_und() + "', '"
                  + "')");

         } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                  "No se Registró, verifique la consola para ver el error",
                  "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         }
      }
      //
```

And the view code:

```
 botonGuardar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                  pabascnt = Integer.parseInt(txtcant.getText());
                  pabasvol = Double.parseDouble(txtvol.getText());
                  AbastosDao abdao = new AbastosDao();
                  AbastosLog parabl = new AbastosLog();
                  parabl.setAbas_cod(pabascod);
                  parabl.setAbas_cnt(pabascnt);
                  parabl.setAbas_vol(pabasvol);
                  parabl.setAbas_und(pabasund);
                  abdao.registrarAbasto(parabl);
                  mostrarDatosConTableModel();

            }

      }); 
      }
```

Where is the error?

I think that the error is sending parameters to the DAO but I don't know.

Comment: `+ miAbasto.getAbas_und() + "', '"` adds an extra comma which makes the query invalid.  Consider changing to use a `PreparedStatement` to set the values.  See also:  SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you should probably research SQL Injection before you go much further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you might convert this to use a PreparedStatement, which will also take care of a number of potential problems including preventing SQL Injection, and data type mapping of the values being inserted. I'd suggest you review the [documentation on using PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). In the meantime, I've included a simple example of how you might use a Prepared Statement.

```
PreparedStatement ps = conex.getConnection().prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO abas001 (abas_cod, abas_cnt, abas_vol, abas_und) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
try {
    ps.setObject(1, miAbasto.getAbas_cod());
    ps.setObject(2, miAbasto.getAbas_cnt());
    ps.setObject(3, miAbasto.getAbas_vol());
    ps.setObject(4, miAbasto.getAbas_und());
    int rowsInserted = ps.executeUpdate();
} . . .
finally {
    ps.close();
}
```

It's important to be aware that PreparedStatements may be reused, and doing so could improve the performance of your application. Additionally, If your application tends to call this method repeatedly for each element of a large set of inputs, you might consider refactoring for batch execution. I'll leave all of this to you as well as adding the necessary and appropriate error handling.